# Regressing the "fixed effect" on time invariant characteristics. Is it possible?

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I would like to use estimations of "fixed effect" from my panel data model as a dependent variable and study whether this depends on time invariant characteristics. 
I've not been able to find an article, text-book, etc., using this methodology which makes me think that there might be *something* precluding one to make such estimation.

If you have some idea on why this is not feasible, or instead, you know some article treating this I would really appreciate if you let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There was essentially the same question asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/100168/241093, and one of the answers provides some information that may be helpful to you.  There is also a link in the comment to the question to a paper that apparently illustrates this method.